# How to fix 'TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting' in Python

Tags: python, string, list

I'm trying to make a code to get two keys from a master key. The key must be a string. For the first, you have to take the even number and for the second, the odds numbers. E.g.: Master key = 18923. First Key = 82, second Key = 193.

I am new to python.

```
masterKey = '18293'
firstKey = ''
secondKey = ''

masterKeyList = list(masterKey)
firstKeyList = list(firstKey)
secondKeyList = list(secondKey)

for digit in masterKeyList:
    if digit % 2 == 0:  # <--- here is the error
        firstKeyList.append(digit)
    else:
        secondKeyList.append(digit)
```

Error message

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

I want to know why this happens, and a solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`digit` is a string. Just typecast it using `int()`:

```
if not int(digit) % 2:
```

The reason your error is occurring is because the modulus operator is also a string formatting operator, but you haven't provided the necessary arguments to string-format '2'

This for-loop will work:

```
for digit in masterKeyList:
    if not int(digit) % 2:
        firstKeyList.append(digit)
    else:
        secondKeyList.append(digit)
```

Answer (score 1):

This error is occurring because `digit` is a string, and `%` in the context of strings is a format operator.

To fix it, convert it into an integer:

```
...
if int(digit) % 2 == 0:
...
```

Answer (score 1):

`digit` is a string in your code, so if you want to apply modulo 2 you need to convert it to a number. That should work fine:

```
masterKey = '18293'
firstKey = ''
secondKey = ''

masterKeyList = list(masterKey)
firstKeyList = list(firstKey)
secondKeyList = list(secondKey)

for digit in masterKeyList:
    if int(digit) % 2 == 0: <--- fixed
        firstKeyList.append(digit)
    else:
        secondKeyList.append(digit)
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be simplified and shortened using list comprehension and `join()` if you need `strings`. In case you prefer `lists` then just remove the `join()`. You can do something like the following:

```py
masterKey = '18293'
firstKey  = "".join([e for e in masterKey if int(e) % 2 == 0])
secondKey = "".join([e for e in masterKey if int(e) % 2 != 0])
```